# Proof of expected value integral

Tags: probability

There is a proposition about expected value from a stochastic processes text that states that if X is a random variable with values in E, and f is a function from E into R, then $$E[f(x)] = \int_E f(t) \,d\phi(t)$$ where the second E should be under the integral symbol.
I am confused as to why the E is used twice. It seems that the first E is the expected value, whereas the second is the set of random variables. It seems like a different symbol should be used. The $\phi (t)$ is the probability distribution function.

Also and more importantly, how do you go about proving this? (No proof provided in the text).

Comment: I am getting the same impression: the $E$ to the left of $[f(x)]$ is the symbol of "expected value".  The $E$ under the integral is the domain of the random variable $f$.

Why does this need proof?  Isn't this the definition of [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value)--see "Absolutely continuous case" in the linked article and beware that their $f$ is your $\phi$.

Comment: The first E stands for "expectation". The second for a set $E$ which is the domain of function $f$. Actually it can be left out. I think that you are dealing with a definition, and not with something that must be proved.

Answer (score 1):

I see some bad notations here. Here is the correct statement with proof: let $X$ be  a masurable function on a measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ with values in a measurable space $(D,\mathcal G)$. Let $\phi (A)=P(X^{-1}(A))$. This defines  a measure on $(D,\mathcal G)$. The formula now is $Ef(X)=\int_D fd\phi$ for any $f:D \to \mathbb R$ which is integrable or non-negative and measurable. To prove this note that this is simply the definition when $f=I_A$ for some $A \in  \mathcal G$. Hence it is true for simple functions. By taking limits we see that it holds for all non-negative and measurable functions $f$. If $f$ is integrable we c an apply this to $f^{+}$ and $f^{-}$ and subtract the second equation from the first.

Comment: Too hard for me to recognize all that in a notation ;). I miss familiarity here.

Comment: @drhab The formula in the question is very familiar to all of us when $X$ takes values in the real line. But it is given here that $X$ take values in some  set $E$ and we have to prove the formula for real functions on $E$. You need a sigma algebra on $E$ for this and $\phi$ is here the measure induced by $X$ on $E$.

Comment: I see now. Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain in simpler terms how the distribution function is used here? And what do you mean by  X inverse? Is there an intuitive explanation for what you have as $P(X^{-1}(A))$?

Comment: $X$ is a map from the original probability space $\Omega$ to $E$. For $A \subset E$,  $X^{-1}(A)$ is defined as $\{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega) \in A\}$